# Hebrew-Spanish-Transliterated Siddur, Nusach Ashkenaz

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book

I'm looking for Siddurim for some friends. Nusach Ashkenaz, Hebrew-Spanish-Transliteration. There seem to be quite a few Nusach Sephardi ones available for purchase online (As well there should be!) and Chabad's "Tehila Hashem", but I can't seem to find this combination. I've been on Artscroll's website, Nehora.com's Spanish section, mislibrosjudaicos.com, judaicapanama, and several Argentinian sites. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I wonder whether you can get by with a Portuguese transliterated _sidur_. Hebrew doesn't have nasal vowels (e.g. ã) or palatal consonants (e.g. nh), so most things transliterated from Hebrew should be the same between the two languages. שׁ would, I'm guessing, be transliterated ch in Portuguese, in which case it could be read in Spanish also. ה may be problematic though.

Comment: @msh210 By the time the user does that they might as well learn English transliteration, or Hebrew itself. The point of transliteration is to make it _easier_ to read Hebrew. If you have to learn a bunch of rules anyway, you might as well learn to read the actual text.

Comment: While the Portuguese workaround may serve in a pinch, it's pretty strange that that would be available rather than Spanish- there are many more Jews in Spanish-speaking countries than in Portugal, Brazil and Angola, and while in many Latin American countries high percentages of Jewish children attend day schools, that's certainly not the case in, say, Argentina or Uruguay